# How to highlight all occurrence of the same variable in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

In Xcode, when I click on a variable's name and wanting to find out the location of the same variable in my code, the Xcode put a very faint line beneath all occurrence, in my case, I tried to find all instance of the "range" variable in my code.

[image]

As you can see, the faint line beneath the variable is very hard to spot, so I was just wondering if there is any way that I can make it more obvious?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way to do this without plugins.

Comment: semi related: if you want to refactor the variable name quickly, click and hover over the variable, then when the dropdown appears can click "edit all in scope"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [AutoHighlightSymbol](https://github.com/chiahsien/AutoHighlightSymbol) plugin. To get it you would need to have [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io/) package manager for Xcode.

> Xcode can highlight instances of selected symbol, but what it does is
>   to add dash lines under the instances, which is hard to be  noticed.
>
> AutoHighlightSymbol is a plugin for Xcode, it adds **background
>   highlight color** to those instances ....

Answer (score 8):

With Xcode 11, you can click on the variable that you want to highlight,

and then press `Control + Command + e`. The highlight effect is as below.

[image: Edit all in scope]

Comment: That's actually "rename in scope". Neat hack though.

Comment: Not the same, but at least it's something.
Shame on Apple for not making it possible to adjust symbol highlight in Themes.